# "WindowedBy Count KStream" throws StreamsException

Tags: spring, count, apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams

I tried to count event from KStream, into time period:

```
    KStream<String, VehicleEventTO> stream = builder.stream("vehicle", Consumed.with(Serdes.String(), new JsonSerde<>(VehicleEventTO.class)));

    KStream<String, VehicleEventTO> streamWithKey = stream.selectKey((key, value) -> value.getId_vehicle().toString());

    KStream<String, Long> streamValueKey = streamWithKey.map((key, value) -> KeyValue.pair(key, value.getId_vehicle()));

    streamValueKey.groupByKey()
                  .windowedBy(TimeWindows.of(Duration.ofMinutes(10).toMillis()))
                  .count(Materialized.with(Serdes.String(), new JsonSerde<>(Long.class)));
```

I've this exception:

> Exception in thread
>   "test-app-87ce164d-c427-4dcf-aa76-aeeb6f8fc943-StreamThread-1"
>   org.apache.kafka.streams.errors.StreamsException: Exception caught in
>   process. taskId=0_0, processor=KSTREAM-SOURCE-0000000000,
>   topic=vehicle, partition=0, offset=160385     at
>   org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.StreamTask.process(StreamTask.java:318)
>     at
>   org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.AssignedStreamsTasks.process(AssignedStreamsTasks.java:94)
>     at
>   org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.TaskManager.process(TaskManager.java:409)
>     at
>   org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.StreamThread.processAndMaybeCommit(StreamThread.java:964)
>     at
>   org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.StreamThread.runOnce(StreamThread.java:832)
>     at
>   org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.StreamThread.runLoop(StreamThread.java:767)
>     at
>   org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.StreamThread.run(StreamThread.java:736)
>   Caused by: org.apache.kafka.streams.errors.StreamsException: A
>   serializer (key:
>   org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.ByteArraySerializer / value:
>   org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.ByteArraySerializer) is not
>   compatible to the actual key or value type (key type: java.lang.String
>   / value type: java.lang.Long). Change the default Serdes in
>   StreamConfig or provide correct Serdes via method parameters.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`groupByKey()` makes use of the default serialisers:

> **`groupByKey()`**
>
> Group the records by their current key into a
>   KGroupedStream while preserving the original values and default
>   serializers and deserializers.

You either have to use `groupByKey(Serialized<K,V> serialized)` or `groupByKey(Grouped<K,V> grouped)`.

The following should do the trick:

```
streamValueKey.groupByKey(Serialized.with(Serdes.String(), Serdes.Long()))
              .windowedBy(TimeWindows.of(Duration.ofMinutes(10).toMillis()))
              .count(Materialized.with(Serdes.String(), new JsonSerde<>(Long.class)));
```